# Unable to load custom font during XCTest in framework I'm creating

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, ios9, xctest

I am creating a new private Framework containing common code among our apps for use with Cocoapods. I want to add the fonts we use for our apps in it. I add the fonts the regular way (created a Resources folder, dropped and copied the fonts, added the entries in the Info.plist, added the Fonts to the Font Book) and I can see and use them in the storyboard:

[image]

My Fonts class looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class USDFont: UIFont {

    let name = "Texta-"

    //Font weights.
    enum USDFontWeight: Int {
        case Thin
        case Light
        case Book
        case Regular
        case Medium
        case Bold
        case Heavy
        case Black
    }

    //Font scales. Goes from -2 to 9.
    var USDFontScaleFactor: [String: CGFloat] =
        ["UIContentSizeCategoryExtraSmall": -2,
         "UIContentSizeCategorySmall": -1,
         "UIContentSizeCategoryMedium": 0,
         "UIContentSizeCategoryLarge": 1,
         "UIContentSizeCategoryExtraLarge": 2,
         "UIContentSizeCategoryExtraExtraLarge": 3,
         "UIContentSizeCategoryExtraExtraExtraLarge": 4,
         "UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityMedium": 5,
         "UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityLarge": 6,
         "UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraLarge": 7,
         "UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraExtraLarge": 8,
         "UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge": 9]

    func iconFontWithSize(fontSize: CGFloat, dynamic: Bool) -> UIFont? {
        let pointSize = fontSizeWithBaseFontSize(fontSize, dynamic: dynamic)
        return UIFont(name: "Insight-Icons", size: pointSize)
    }

    func fontWithFontSize(fontSize: CGFloat, weight fontWeight: USDFontWeight, italic: Bool) -> UIFont {
        var fontName: String = ""
        if italic {
           fontName = "\(name)\(fontWeight)It"
        } else {
            fontName = "\(name)\(fontWeight)"
        }

        return UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize)!
    }

    func fontWithBaseFontSize(baseFontSize: CGFloat, weight fontWeight: USDFontWeight, italic: Bool, dynamic: Bool) -> UIFont {
        let fontSize = fontSizeWithBaseFontSize(baseFontSize, dynamic: dynamic)
        return fontWithFontSize(fontSize, weight: fontWeight, italic: italic)
    }

    func fontSizeWithBaseFontSize(baseFontSize: CGFloat, dynamic: Bool) -> CGFloat {
        if dynamic {
            if let fontSizeFactor = USDFontScaleFactor[UIApplication.sharedApplication().preferredContentSizeCategory] {
                return baseFontSize + (fontSizeFactor * 0.8)
            }
        }
        return baseFontSize
    }
}
```

However, in my Unit Test for this framework, I have the following test:

```
func testUSDFont() {
        let myFont = USDFont()

        //Check which fonts available
        for family: String in UIFont.familyNames()
        {
            print("\(family)")
            for names: String in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(family)
            {
                print("== \(names)")
            }
        }

        let insightIcons = myFont.iconFontWithSize(20.0, dynamic: true)
        print("------ INSIGHT ICONS: \(insightIcons) ------")
        XCTAssert(true, "True")
    }
```

During the XCTest, neither my Insight-Icons font nor my Texta fonts are available. When I try to load them, I get nil. When I try to print them using UIFont.familyNames() I don't see my custom fonts. What am I missing?

Comment: If you have any updates on the issue - please share, I'm experiencing the same issue. I can't understand, however, why custom font's are available when testing an app rather than framework then. UI testing of a framework is sometimes needed.

Comment: @gameCon Did you see my solution? I found a suitable workaround by using CGFontCreateWithDataProvider and passing the font as data.

Comment: I did and upvoted;) It' working and it's good to make font life easier

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by loading the font file as data and then creating a font using CGFontCreateWithDataProvider. Here is my loadCustomFont method:

```
func loadCustomFont(name: String, fontExtension: String) -> Bool {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let bundleURL = NSBundle(forClass: USDFont.self).bundleURL
    do {
        let contents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(bundleURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [], options: .SkipsHiddenFiles)
        for url in contents {
            if url.pathExtension == fontExtension {
                let fontData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
                let provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(fontData)
                if let font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider) {
                    CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, nil)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
    return true
}
```

Once I loaded fonts this way (instead of the usual Info.plist way), I was able to load the font during the XCTest.

Answer (score 10):

For newcomers: I updated [Rommels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605688/rommeltj) answer for Swift 4 and wrapped into a helper class:

```
import UIKit

class FontLoader {

    @discardableResult
    class func loadCustomFonts(for fontExtension: String) -> Bool {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let bundleURL = Bundle(for: FontLoader.self).bundleURL
        do {
            let contents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: bundleURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [], options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
            for url in contents {
                if url.pathExtension == fontExtension {
                    guard let fontData = NSData(contentsOf: url) else {
                        continue
                    }
                    let provider = CGDataProvider(data: fontData)
                    let font = CGFont(provider!)
                    CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, nil)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you both.

Answer (score 3):

I've also run into this problem myself today. It seems that custom fonts are not accessible from the Tests. I even tried to add them to the Test targets to no success. My suspicion is that this might be a bug, but I think it can also be a planned restriction from Apple. I suggest, if you haven't done so, to offer a runtime substitute of the system font, which is always available just in case so your test won't crash. Again, I don't know what you are testing and if loading fonts is an important part of your test, but at least your test won't break and you won't break your code either. This is what I did:

```
let dashboardValueLargeFont = UIFont(name: "Interstate", size: 70.0) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(70.0)
```

Hope it helps until we find out if this is a known restriction or a bug. Either way, it needs to be addressed in future versions.

Comment: I was able to find a workaround but I forgot to post the answer. See above.

Comment: Oh great! Thanks for sharing @RommelTJ